# Hide JQuery css on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which I want when  someone click on any button , the button border show up . This is my JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#button1").on('click', function () {
var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
$.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
    $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
    $( "#button1" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );

});

});

});


$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#button2").on('click', function () {
var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
$.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('a').fadeOut()).done(function () {
    $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
    $( "#button2" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );

});

});

 });
```

When I click on button1 , the border shows up , that's fine . 
BUT when i click the button2 , i want the border of button1 gone away ( Hide when clicking other buttons ) . and so on , i have 9 buttons in my website which i gave them all ID and i want each button have an border when they are active ( someone click on them ).

Comment: and btw when i click on button2 , the border of button1 is still there on button1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('[id^=button]').css("border","none");
```

or

```
$('button').css("border","none");
```

and then

```
$( "#button2" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line `$( "#button1" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );` below `$( "#button2" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );`